# Как понять что программа на удалённом сервере linux закончила работу

Tags: linux

Подключаюсь к серверу по ssh. Сервер на линукс и видимо с bash
Есть программа (HISAT2) и файлы которые надо ей обработать, причём обработка одного файла занимает довольно много времени
После команды в терминале hisat2 не даёт никакой обратной связи, т.е. просто пустая строчка  + нельзя ввести никаких команд
Через минут пять подключение по ssh отваливается, программа работу свою по идее доводит до конца, создаёт файл вывода

Вопрос: как после переподключения определить, что процесс выполнения команды завершён? Потому что файл вывода может создаваться ещё до завершения записи в него
И при этом на сервере может быть несколько работающих с этой программой (в разных директориях)

Comment: Как я понял, HISAT ничего не выводит в случае завершения без ошибок. В таком случае можно обернуть запуск программы в bash-скрипт, который с помощью какой-нибудь переменной `$OUTPUT = $(команда запуска hisat);` будет спрашивать был ли у hisat вывод в случае ошибки. Если да, то записать этот вывод куда-нибудь в лог-файл. Если нет, то тоже записать об этом в лог-файл, сказав что всё хорошо завершилось.
UPD: более крутого способа не знаю - делал бы так

Comment: Запустить в screen/tmux. Тогда после отвала ssh можно будет переподключится.

Comment: 1. Если сервер - вычислительный и многопользовательский, то там может быть предусмотрен специальный язык управления задачами (типа, OpenPBS), а за такой запуск как у Вас администраторы могут дать по шее; 2. Даже если программа ничего не выводит на терминал, она может возвращать значение, которое можно проверить; 3. при запуске *обычные* программы привязаны к управляющем терминалу и при обрыве сессии ssh они убиваются системой (это можно обойти через screen/tmux или при запуске через nohup в фоновом режиме).